# How to position tabs and use arrow to navigate?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

i am trying to develop a preview to show banners. On my preview, I am using clickable tabs to choose. What I am trying to do?
I am trying to align the tabs on a single row where multiple tabs will be on one single line as well as two arrows on the left and right to navigate the tabs in order to choose.

This is my CSS for tabs

```
#tabs {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        #tabs div {
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            color: white;
            padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
            /* margin-left: 2px; */
            cursor: pointer;
            transform-origin: center;
            background-color: #6a6e94;
        }

        .active,#tabs div:hover {
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px black;
            background-color: var(--default_color)!important;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    @foreach ($data as $id => $row)
         <div id="version{{$id}}" class="versions @if(Helper::getFeedbackStatus($id) == 1) active @endif">
                {{ $i++ }}.{{ Helper::getFeedbackName($id) }}</div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Yes the tabs are dynamic

And this is a sample that I am trying to overcome
[What I am trying to do](https://ibb.co/CHVqBmg)

I don't know where to start actually.

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap;` should be `flex-wrap: nowrap;`

Comment: Thanks for the help brother now the tabs are in one single line. much appreciated!